# Bugs and issues with the ImapMailbox.php

Tags: php, codeigniter, imap

I have written a PHP script in CodeIgniter that uses the ImapMailbox.php library(https://github.com/barbushin/php-imap) to sync emails from a remote IMAP/POP server to our web application and I've run into a number of issues. When I sync from a gmail account everything works fine but when I try to sync from a GoDaddy email account, we get the following errors.

```
Undefined property: stdClass::$from /var/www/html/application/libraries/ImapMailbox.php 435
Trying to get property of non-object /var/www/html/application/libraries/ImapMailbox.php 435
Unknown: Warning: message has unknown MIME version (errflg=3) Unknown 0
Unknown: Ignoring nested encoding of multipart contents (errflg=3) Unknown 0
Unknown: Warning: MIME header encountered in non-MIME message (errflg=3) Unknown 0
Unknown: Missing parameter (errflg=3) Unknown 0
Unknown: Must use comma to separate addresses: Delivery System (errflg=3) Unknown 0
Unknown: Missing parameter value: CONTENT-TRANSFER-ENCODING (errflg=3) Unknown 0
Unknown: Unexpected characters at end of parameters: : 8bit (errflg=3) Unknown 0
Unknown: Invalid quoted-printable sequence: = Hump Day Special: Save on our July 14th Spring/Klein Pocketbook mail=

ing




(errflg=3) Unknown 0
imap_fetchheader(): Bad message number /var/www/html/application/libraries/ImapMailbox.php 428
iconv(): Wrong charset, conversion from `X-UNKNOWN' to `utf-8//IGNORE' is not allowed /var/www/html/application/libraries/ImapMailbox.php 641
```

Does anyone have any suggestions on fixing the above issues?

Comment: Can we see the code that is generating this error?

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code is that you call `imap_close()` before you actually finish working with your emails. Try leaving open your IMAP connection to check this.

```
Unknown: Warning: message has unknown MIME version (errflg=3) Unknown 0
```

This most likely says that connection is not ready and no data received, so validation fails, or POP3/IMAP server is working wrong.